# How to keep only unique rows in Snowflake?

Tags: python, sql-server, api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distinct-values

I'm currently loading data from an API into Snowflake but can't find a good method of keeping only unique rows in a table. There is no guaranteed unique key from this API.

I've explored:

1. One option I researched was to use the not matched clause, but it appears that's only when there's a key and not for the entire row at least as far as I can find. This method would've used a temp table to do the comparison.
2. Another option would be to select distinct from the source table to the temp table and then load it back into the source. I don't like this method, albeit simple, due to there being a moment when the source table would be without data.
3. I've also tried a few tests to make a hash and thereby create my own key representation of the row contents as an additional field before I load. This would probably be the more inefficient method and seems the most nonstandard. This is possible but as a last resort if I can't use the existing infrastructure I'm hoping has a solution.

If anyone has any working solution on any of these three path's with sample query I'd greatly appreciate it.

Pseudo-code for what I'm looking for

```
sql = "MERGE INTO INVOICES USING INVOICES_TEMP WHEN NOT MATCHED"
cur.execute(sql)
```

Edit: This way results in no errors but I can execute it over and over and it keeps adding the same rows to TABLE and doesn't block the duplicates like I want. So perhaps I have the syntax down but my usage of the table/fields is incorrect.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE USING TABLE_TEMP ON TABLE.FIELD1=TABLE_TEMP.FIELD1
 AND TABLE.FIELD2=TABLE_TEMP.FIELD2 AND TABLE.FIELD3=TABLE_TEMP.FIELD3
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES
 (TABLE_TEMP.FIELD1,TABLE_TEMP.FIELD2,TABLE_TEMP.FIELD3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correct, I'd prefer your first option. You can extend the column-comparison within the MERGE-statement to all columns so you are not limited to the keys only.

```
merge into target_table using source_table 
    on target_table.col1 = source_table.col1
    and target_table.col2 = source_table.col2
    and target_table.col3 = source_table.col3
    ...
```

More infos about merge: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: Is that exact statement ending in “when not matched” to run successfully? Is there any way to not have to specify all columns? My main worry in that approach is inefficiency but perhaps it’s the most efficient option.

Comment: If you want to compare all columns you have to specify all comparisons, yes. Maybe calculating a hash over all columns and only comparing the hash is faster.

Comment: Sorry about all the edits. Check out my latest post. I have the syntax down or at least close, there's no SQL errors, but it doesn't prevent duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Disregard above, figured it out, your syntax was great thanks.